# What is the purpose of these diodes in the EMI filter?

Tags: power-electronics, switch-mode-power-supply, emc, emi-filtering

What is the purpose of the D1 and D2 diodes in the below EMI filter?
I've seen diodes placed there in front of EMI filters so I added the to my circuit, and I want to know the purpose.
I have not equipped them, which is why I have a "DNI" at the moment.

Input is a 28 volt battery. It's my image and schematic.

[image: t is]

Comment: What's in front of diodes D1 and D2 ?

Comment: @Vincent A 28VDC battery

Comment: In case of reverse polarity, they insure that something burns up. Having diodes like that on the supply doesn't make sense, but it can make sense on signal lines, when you take a signal from a noisy environment and want to ensure it stays within expected voltage limits (0 to 3.3V etc). In such situations a corresponding diode to a positive voltage reference is also used. Small signal diodes will do in that case, no need for 1N400x.

Answer (score 3):

With a positive DC input relative to ground D1 & D2 would serve no function.

If the battery was incorrectly connected with reversed polarity  D1 & D2 would short circuit the battery and draw large current.  If a fuse was fitted it may blow, depending on fuse rating and supply current capability and wiring resistance and more.

As shown D1 & D2 have "DNI" next to them which means "Do Not Install".